# Installing twine fails because cannot uninstall 'pkginfo'

Tags: python, distutils, pypi, twine

I need guidance on what I should do in this situation:

```
C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\2016Coding\testdist>pip install twine
Collecting twine
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/ae/9cfdff186dd4812c59bad890435538858f13fe43dbe6923e0fb20f0adfc8/twine-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: requests!=2.15,!=2.16,>=2.5.0 in c:\users\dave\desktop\2016coding\environments\ipython_env\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from twine) (2.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-toolbelt>=0.8.0 in c:\users\dave\desktop\2016coding\environments\ipython_env\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from twine) (0.8.0)
Collecting pkginfo>=1.4.2 (from twine)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/fe/f32a48d48f40a7209be9825fba2566cab92364787cf37de2e08300dd6ce7/pkginfo-1.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.14 in c:\users\dave\desktop\2016coding\environments\ipython_env\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from twine) (4.23.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=0.7.0 in c:\users\dave\desktop\2016coding\environments\ipython_env\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from twine) (38.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\dave\desktop\2016coding\environments\ipython_env\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests!=2.15,!=2.16,>=2.5.0->twine) (1.22)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\dave\desktop\2016coding\environments\ipython_env\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests!=2.15,!=2.16,>=2.5.0->twine) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\dave\desktop\2016coding\environments\ipython_env\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests!=2.15,!=2.16,>=2.5.0->twine) (2018.1.18)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in c:\users\dave\desktop\2016coding\environments\ipython_env\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests!=2.15,!=2.16,>=2.5.0->twine) (2.6)
Installing collected packages: pkginfo, twine
  Found existing installation: pkginfo 1.3.2
Cannot uninstall 'pkginfo'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

I can't find another reference to this issue anywhere on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pip install twine --ignore-installed
```

Comment: Works, but overwrites files such as `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chardet/__init__.py` that were originally created by the OS package manager.